# Nodemon doesn't restart when changes are made on discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot on JavaScript using discord.js. I am running it via nodemon, but when I'm making changes to the script, the script doesn't restart. Please help me!

- **index.js**

```
const { Client, IntentsBitField } = require("discord.js");

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMembers,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.MessageContent,
  ],
});

client.on('ready', (c) => {
    console.info(`✔ ${c.user.tag} is online.`);
});

client.on('messageCreate', (msg) => {
    if (msg.content == 'Hello!')
        msg.reply('Hi!');
});

client.login(
  "my key"
);
```

The command is `nodemon src/index.js`

The log is:

```
[nodemon] 2.0.22
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node src/index.js`
✔ [RR] Military Bot#1578 is online.
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
```

I tried changing the command from `nodemon src/index.js` to `nodemon -L src/index.js`, but it didn't work. And then I tried running from the terminal instead of the `package.json` but again, nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try executing

```
npm -g uninstall nodemon
```

then

```
npm -g install nodemon
```

The fixed that I found.